# Angular Karma unit testing wait for isEmpty to emit value

Tags: angular, rxjs, karma-runner

I have following code for handling errors:

```
              catchError((error) => {
                return statement ? EMPTY : otherValue;
              }),
```

I am trying to write an unit test for this. Here what I have achieved.

```
  it('test description', fakeAsync(() => {
    let saved: boolean;
    action = new action({ data: 'some data'});
    action$.next(action);

    effects.save.pipe(isEmpty()).subscribe((data: boolean) => {
      console.log('data:', data);
      saved = data;
    });
    flush();

    console.log('saved:', saved);
    expect(saved).toBeTrue();
  }));
```

My output looks like:

````
```
'saved:', undefined
'data:', true
Error: Expected undefined to be true.
```
````

What can I improve to make this test pass?

Comment: Looks like  `action$`  is your test case is some kind of `Subject`. If thats the case, since `isEmpty()` only emits when the source observable completes, you'll need to call `complete()` on `action$` after the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to synchronously access asynchronous value. You should use a `done` function inside the async handler (inside `subscribe()`).

```
it('test description', done => {
  action = new action({ data: 'some data'});
  action$.next(action);

  effects.save.pipe(isEmpty()).subscribe((data: boolean) => {
    console.log('data:', data);
    expect(data).toBeTrue();
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: After implementing your code, I got following error:
```Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 10000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)```

Should I increase this value or there is workaround?

Comment: Increasing ```jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL``` doesn't change anything, I am still stuck with the error above.

Comment: Then it looks like the chain doesn't emit at all.